# How to fix cURL Post doesn't post data?

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, laravel-4

> Situation

- I have a PHP script that suppose to sent a POST request to my server from my Windows 7 machine.
- So now I have 2 things :

  ```
  1- Standalone PHP script running ( on a Windows 7 machine )

  2- A function that receive data from what I post ( On my server )
  ```

Here is what they look like :

> 1- Standalone PHP script running ( on a Windows 7 machine )

```
<?php 

        // Load and Convert : csv > UTF8 > array > JSON
        $file_name = 'inventory.csv';
        $file_path = 'C:\\QuickBooks\\'.$file_name;
        $csv= file_get_contents($file_path);
        $utf8_csv = utf8_encode($csv);
        $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $utf8_csv));
        $json = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        //echo $json; // It's working !

        $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/api_inventory/url?key=*****");

        // Set cURL options 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:*****");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json' => $json));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Execute with clean exit 
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo $response;

?
```

- I think I did something wrong in the cURL section.

> 2- A function that receive data from what I post ( On my server )

```
public function post() {
        $json = json_decode(Input::get('json'));
        return count($json);
    }
```

- Finally, as a result, when I run my PHP script, I keep getting `0`.
- Which mean I got the response back from `return count($json);`, but wrong response. :(
- It seems like nothing is inside my $json variable.

I just couldn't figure it out - what is it exactly that stop my cURL from `Posting` data to my server, I'm wondering if someone can help me explain all of this.

Comment: Have you checked the raw post data to ensure your server script is receiving the posted data?

Comment: Basic debugging: don't chain your calls. first see what `Input::get(...)` returns. Then try to decode it, var_dump() the decoded text, etc...

Comment: try this way :  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);` or if you need your variant then : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('json' => $json)));`

Comment: Thank you all,  for your suggestion.

Comment: did it really help ?

Comment: idk yet. I am on it. I got a little issue with my Sublime Text. I will let you guys know. Thanks for checking back with me.

Comment: @KimAlexander :  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('json' => $json))); ! Work !

Comment: Why do I need to do `json_encode(array('json' => $json))` again ? I don't get it. I did that already on the top section of my code - see here `$json = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Answer (score 2):

**Delete** this 2 lines:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json' => $json));`

**Add** this 1 line:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('json' => $json)));`

### Work 100% !

Thanks to `@KimAlexander` suggestion.